# Compute daily mean with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a function that will calculate the means of values in column "A" of a pandas dataframe that fall on the same date. Is there an approach to do this that is more efficient than the list comprehension in the last line?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def daily_mean(df,date,col):
     return df[date][col].mean()

data = np.random.rand(100)
columns = ['A']
times = pd.date_range('20180101',freq='9H',periods=100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=times,columns=columns)

dates = df.index.strftime('%Y%m%d').unique()
means = [daily_mean(df,date,'A') for date in dates]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `pd.Grouper` API. Also, this will retain the DataFrame, so it's a win-win.

```
means = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D')).mean()
```

Or, you can group on the floor of the datetime index.

```
means = df.groupby(df.index.floor('D')).mean()
```

```
means.head(10)
                   A
2018-01-01  0.412354
2018-01-02  0.301209
2018-01-03  0.710357
2018-01-04  0.158135
2018-01-05  0.720308
2018-01-06  0.281862
2018-01-07  0.489486
2018-01-08  0.287808
2018-01-09  0.463117
2018-01-10  0.512963
```

I prefer approach #1 since `pd.Grouper` should be more efficient than grouping on an unrelated series/array (as in the second form).

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
df.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(key='index', freq='D'))['A'].mean()

index
2018-01-01    0.412354
2018-01-02    0.301209
2018-01-03    0.710357
2018-01-04    0.158135
2018-01-05    0.720308
...
```

Comment: If you do not specify a key, the grouping will happen on the index by default. Nice answer ;)

Comment: Arrigato, Sensei.